# BigQuery [PHP API] get list of accessible projects

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I used below PHP code based on the GCP documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) to fetch a list of all the projects which can be accessed with the selected service account.

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=acc-key.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('SampleApp');
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform');
$service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);

$optParams = [];

do {
    $response = $service->projects->listProjects($optParams);
    foreach ($response['projects'] as $project) {
        print_r($project);
    }
    $optParams['pageToken'] = $response->getNextPageToken();
} while ($optParams['pageToken']);
```

This does work and fetches only one or two projects from a total of 25 projects which can be accessed with this key.

I confirmed the permission on other projects by accessing them while providing an exclusive project name.

Any hints on what could be the missing part?

EDIT: [Based on Mikhail's answer]

I get below error if I change

```
$service = new Google_Service_Bigquery($client);
```

to

```
$service = new Google_Service_CloudResourceManager($client);
```

I get below error

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Google_Service_CloudResourceManager::$projects in /tests/ListFullSchema.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined property: Google_Service_CloudResourceManager::$projects in /tests/ListFullSchema.php on line 18
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listProjects() on null in /tests/ListFullSchema.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /tests/ListFullSchema.php on line 18

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function listProjects() on null in /tests/ListFullSchema.php:18
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because Cloud Resource Manager v2 doesn't have projects.list method, but [v1](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list) does. If you'd like to use [Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) for this task, you can download the [v1.1.8](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases/tag/v1.1.8) and install it following the instructions [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#download-the-release). Then you can run the PHP code like in [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list#examples).

You should use:

```
$service = new Google_Service_CloudResourceManager($client);
```

Alternatively, you can use Python, like in the [example](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/list#examples). The service version is specified inside the code so you don't need custom installations.